# Are immigrants from other English-speaking countries required to take the English test?

Tags: citizenship, usa

The [US government web site](https://www.uscis.gov/us-citizenship/naturalization-test) describes the English test. I couldn't see anything about people who came from another English-speaking country such as Canada, UK, Australia, New Zeeland, etc. Obviously, they already know English. Are they exempt from taking the English test?

Comment: It should be noted that the English test, for a fluent speaker of English, would normally consist of reading one of three sentences aloud and then writing one of three sentences from dictation.  The test is described at https://www.uscis.gov/policy-manual/volume-12-part-e-chapter-2, and for anyone fluent in English, with basic literacy, it shouldn't take more than a minute or two.

Comment: I got naturalized about 8 years ago. There must have been a language test, but apparently it was so quick and easy that I don't remember it. The officer can quickly tell whether you are fluent or not. Keep in mind that not all people that from an English speaking country actually speak English well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page you cite discusses the Naturalization Test administered by the USCIS. The page contains [this link](https://www.uscis.gov/us-citizenship/citizenship-through-naturalization/exceptions-accommodations), which leads to another page which discusses the English language test. That page, in turn, contains [this further link](https://www.uscis.gov/us-citizenship/citizenship-through-naturalization/exceptions-accommodations) to a page discussion "Exceptions and Accommodations" regarding the tests.

The last-linked page contains this text:

[image]

Thus, it appears that an English-speaker who hasn't lived in the United States for the required durations is not exempt from taking the English test.

Comment: If I applied for US citizenship, I would be exempt under both rules. However, as far as I can tell the specific English test is trivial, and the main benefit of exemption is being able to take the civics test in one's native language, with a translator.